# Adding code to a function stops the function from working(unity)

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine

I have a recurring problem with adding code to unity. Every time I add code to something, it won't work after I add the code, even if I delete the code. For example:

**New code**

```
if(switchSidesToggle.isOn)
{
    if (team1Button.position == leftButtonPos)
    {
        team1Button.position = leftButtonPos;
        team1SetPos.position = leftSetPos;
        team1TimeoutTrans.position = leftTimeoutPos;
        team2Button.position = rightButtonPos;
        team2SetPos.position = rightSetPos;
        team2TimeoutTrans.position = rightTimeoutPos;
    }
    else
    {
        team1Button.position = leftButtonPos;
        team1TimeoutTrans.position = leftTimeoutPos;
        team1SetPos.position = leftSetPos;
        team2Button.position = rightButtonPos;
        team2TimeoutTrans.position = rightTimeoutPos;
        team2SetPos.position = rightSetPos;
    }
}
```

**Old code**

```
if(switchSidesToggle.isOn)
{
    if (team1Button.position == leftButtonPos)
    {
        team1Button.position = leftButtonPos;
        team1TimeoutTrans.position = leftTimeoutPos;
        team2Button.position = rightButtonPos;
        team2TimeoutTrans.position = rightTimeoutPos;
    }
    else
    {
        team1Button.position = leftButtonPos;
        team1TimeoutTrans.position = leftTimeoutPos;
        team2Button.position = rightButtonPos;
        team2TimeoutTrans.position = rightTimeoutPos;
    }
}
```

The thing that changes are the `team1SetPos` and `team2SetPos` lines. As soon as I added these to my code, it started to not switch sides at all. Can someone help me?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it's not working", but do you realize you have the exact same code in both the `if` and the `else` blocks? The inner `if` condition is meaningless...

Comment: this isn't the full code, there is a reason why its like that and by its not working i mean that it won't switch sides anymore at all.

Comment: Is there a type issue? Are you sure leftTimeoutPos isn't a null?

Comment: it switches only when one side wins a game, not both(its a scoreboard app)

Comment: are you sure you're not tgetting an exception? if an exception is thrown, the code after the line with the exception is not executed

Comment: My vote would be either team1SetPos or team2SetPos is null.